# ReactJS for loop only displaying the last value in firebase query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop an array using for loop. As soon as the variable goes inside the firebase query, only the last value is displayed. Any idea why this is happening?

```
const handleClose = () => {
        var tpList = TP;
        for (var v in tpList) {
            var tp = tpList[v];
            console.log(tp);
            Firebase.database().ref("Student").child(tp + "/Name/").once('value').then((res) => {
                console.log("Name of " + tp + " is " + res.val());
            })
        }
```

The first console log works perfeclty fine, showing the correct values from index 0-5. However, the second console log shows only the index value of 5. Any suggestions what could be wrong here?

Comment: use `let` instead of `var` in the loop.

Comment: you should accept/upvote answer if it helped.

Comment: @giorgim I did, but I get a notification saying "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you'd use `let` instead of `var` in the loop:

```
const handleClose = () => {
    var tpList = TP;
    for (let v in tpList) { // Use let here
      let tp = tpList[v];   // (optional) Also here to keep the scope inside the loop
      console.log(tp);
      Firebase.database().ref("Student").child(tp + "/Name/").once('value').then((res) => {
        console.log("Name of " + tp + " is " + res.val());
      })
    }
```

The reasons for this is that in ES6 when using `let` in a loop, the declared variable will get a new binding for each iteration of the loop, so the closure will correctly capture each value of `v`, instead of capturing only the last one as it happens when using `var`.

Comment: Please do explain on why  let instead of var inside a for loop, probably some insights about lexical scoping of variables in java script....